# RECEBER JSON DO JAVASCRIP NO PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

Galera estou aprendendo ainda sobre JSON, e criei um arquivo js que envia para o meu php só que ao receber no php ele dá erro de  Undefined index: data. Segue códigos:

ARQUIVO JAVASCRIPT:

```
      var usuario = {
    'nome': 'João',
    'profissao': 'Engenheiro',
    'cidade': 'São Paulo'
  }
  
  var dados = JSON.stringify(usuario);
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'teste11.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data: dados},
    success: function(result){
      // Retorno se tudo ocorreu normalmente
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Retorno caso algum erro ocorra
    }
  });
```

ARQUIVO PHP

```
<?php
ob_start();
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
require_once '../class/conexao2.php';
global $pdo;

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$usuario = $_POST['data'];

$dados = json_decode($usuario, true);

var_dump($dados);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu mudei poucas coisas no seu código:

No JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    var usuario =  JSON.stringify({"nome" : "João", "profissao" : "Engenheiro", "cidade" : "São Paulo"})
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'teste.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {dados : usuario},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (s)=>{ 
            //exibe no console o resultado para sucesso
            console.log(s)
        },
        error: (e)=>{ 
            //exibe no console o erro
            console.log(e) 
        }
    })//end ajax
</script>
```

Apenas para ficar menos verboso encurtei o código para criar o JSON armazenando na variável usuario.

Depois mudei a linha **"data"** para **"data: {dados:usuario}"**, além de adicionar o **dataType**.

Já no PHP:

```
<?php

//verifica se existe o índice dados na superglobal POST
if( isset($_POST['dados']) )
{
    //envia para saída
    echo $_POST['dados'];
}
```

O RESULTADO:
[image: o resultado]

:D

Answer (score 0):

Fiz os teste aqui, excluindo as 4 primeiras linhas do seu Arquivo PHP.

Particularmente quando passo os dados no ajax, passo entre aspas, se caso passar mais de um array, poder acessar pela chave como por exemplo `data: {'usuario': dados}`.

Ainda no seu arquivo PHP, na última linha, pode alterar de `var_dump($dados)` para `echo json_encode($dados)` se quiser visualizar o objeto.
Como no header está informando `Content-Type: application/json`, o PHP espera que você exiba os resultados em formato JSON.

Se não quiser exibir os dados em formato de objeto, e sim um array (caso for tratar os dados e quiser fazer com array), pode retirar `header application/json`. Ou ainda mantendo o header, pode com `echo json_encode($usuario)`.
Nesse caso alterando qual variável será impressa.

Segue meu código que funcionou aqui:

ARQUIVO JAVASCRIPT

```
var usuario = {
    'nome': 'João',
    'profissao': 'Engenheiro',
    'cidade': 'São Paulo'
}

var dados = JSON.stringify(usuario);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'teste1.php',
    data: {data: dados},
    success: function(res){
        console.log(res)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown)
    }
})
```

ARQUIVO PHP

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

$usuario = $_POST['data'];

$dados = json_decode($usuario, true);
echo json_encode($dados);
```

Espero ter ajudado, e bons estudos!